# Looping an already working code to simplify it

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop this code with a two cells step until I get to AT44. Is it possible to help me on that one. I need to run it on cell 16-18-20 etc... until 44.

Basically, I've got an If function in column AT that tells my macro to Clear the content of column AB and locked it or unlocked it if false.

```
If Range("AT16") = "Vrai" Then
Range("AB16").ClearContents
Range("AB16").Locked = True
Else:
Range("AB16").Locked = False
End If
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a for loop with step 2

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 64 Step 2
    Range("A" & i).Value = i
Next i

End Sub
```

Will output 2 on row 2, 4 on row 4, etc. on the activesheet.

In your case:

```
For i = 16 to 44 step 2
    If Range("AT" & i ) = "Vrai" Then
        Range("AB" & i).ClearContents
        Range("AB" & i).Locked = True
    Else
        Range("AB" & i).Locked = False
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks! If only I could understand how it works ;) !

Comment: Read [this](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html) for an extremely basic intro.